# Accessing HTTP Error Response Body from HttpInterceptor in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http-error, angular-http-interceptors

I have an HttpInterceptor to catch errors and display them in a modal. Besides error code and message, I would also like to show the body of the response which actually holds a more precise description of the error (e.g. on a 500 internal server error).
How can I achieve this in angular? (I am using version 4.3.6.)

I already looked at related questions but answers like HttpErrorResponse._body or similar don't work for me.
Also, when inspecting the error response in the console, HttpErrorResponse.error is set to null.

Here is how my interceptor currently looks:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  public constructor(private httpErrorService: HttpErrorService) { }

  public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).do(event => {
    }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.log('HTTPERROR INTERCEPTOR');
      console.log(error);
      if (error.status >= 400) {
        this.httpErrorService.onError(error);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### The answer applies to versions of Angular below 6.

The body should be available in the `error` property, so:

```
return next.handle(req).do(event => {
}, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
  console.log(error.error); // body
  ...
});
```

Here is the gist of the implementation [from the sources](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7231f5e26a9d319730373ed6ea871d7d7eb2dc6c/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L218):

```
if (ok) {
  ...
} else {
  // An unsuccessful request is delivered on the error channel.
  observer.error(new HttpErrorResponse({
    // The error in this case is the response body (error from the server).
    error: body,   <--------------------
    headers,
    status,
    statusText,
    url: url || undefined,
  }));
}
```

To learn more about mechanics behind interceptors read:

- [Insider’s guide into interceptors and HttpClient mechanics in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/insiders-guide-into-interceptors-and-httpclient-mechanics-in-angular-103fbdb397bf)

Comment: Thanks! It indeed works now. I was on version 4.3.6 actually (also updated in my original question) and there the error was null. But now on version 4.4.6 everything works fine.

Comment: I was about to capture the error messages, I am pursuing how to extract the success messages when the API request has been completed successfully say status code 200/201 etc.  How can I pass the http response from  `return next.handle(req).do(event=> {console.log(event);//gives whole http response})` how can I return this repsonse to my component from where I am making request. I am using ngrx 4

Comment: This is no longer the case in Angular6, error.error returns a Blob, not the actual body string...

Comment: @reven, thanks for the info, it means they fixed it.

Comment: @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard so how to get the body from HttpErrorResponse when error.error is returning a blob ?

Comment: @NitishKumar, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you please ask another question with more details?

Comment: @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard Here is what I wanted to ask 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758280/how-to-get-body-from-httperrorresponse-in-angular-6

Answer (score 7):

To make full use of Typescript I usually create an interface that extends HttpErrorResponse:

```
interface APIErrorResponse extends HttpErrorResponse {
   error: {
      id?: string
      links?: { about: string }
      status: string
      code?: string
      title: string
      detail: string
      source?: {
         pointer?: string
         parameter?: string
      }
      meta?: any
      }
}
```

After that, just assign APIErrorResponse instead of HttpErrorResponse to your error object and access your server's custom error as mentioned above: error.error