# Angular handleError: How to get custom API error messages?

Tags: angular, api, error-handling, response

I'm trying to solve another Angular problem - can you help me? In my component I have a login function - like this:

```
    onLogin() {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      const email = this.loginForm.get(['email']).value;
      const password = this.loginForm.get(['password']).value;

      this.ls.login(email, password).subscribe(
        result => {
          this.saveToken(result);
        },
        error => {
          this.errorMessage = error;
          this.loginForm.reset();
        }
    );

    } else {
      this.updateErrorMessage();
    }
  }
```

My service function looks like that:

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<string> {

    const apiUrl = environment.apiHostLumen + '/admin/login?email=' + email + '&password=' + password;

    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(apiUrl, options).pipe(
                    retry(3),
                    map(res => res.json()),
                    map(data => {
                      return data.token;
                    }),
                    catchError(this.ehs.handleError('login'))
    );

  }
```

Now I have implemented the function for error handling exactly as described in the documentation of Angular. I have outsourced the feature and it looks like that:

```
handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<T> => {

      const userMessage = error.message;

      return throwError(userMessage);
    };
  }
```

**But how it's possible to access the body of the API response?** `error.message` is always undefined. I only have access to the `status` code and `url`. How can I access the response body if the API returns an error code different from `200` ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Typescript tells me `error.json()` is not available for type `HttpErrorResponse`

Comment: can you share your server side code, there might be case its returning error object without message

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as its already answered by OP

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `HttpInterceptor` for this. From that you can handle all your http errors in a single class. You can read more about [Intercepting requests and responses](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) in the angular official doumetation.

And by using `intercept` method you can intercept each and every request and response.

```
 public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next
      .handle(req)
      .pipe(catchError(err => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          this.onError(err);
        }
        return throwError(err);
      }));
  }



 private onError(response: HttpErrorResponse): void {
    const status: number = response.status;
    const serverErrorMessage = response.error;

    switch(status) {
      case 400:
        console.log("Bad request"); //or you can print the serverErrorMessage
      case 404:
        console.log("Not found");
    }
  }
```

Comment: that is not needed in my application i get details without doing this stuff

Comment: But you have to handle the error of every request by your self. Same code will be repeated agin and again. That's not a good practice. When you implement a `HttpInterceptor` you don't have to do that. It will be handled by the interceptor. It will save your time.

Comment: I have found the mistake, but nevertheless I will read in on this topic - it sounds interesting

Answer (score 1):

You can do `error.error`, which should give you the error response from the server.

```
handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<T> => {

      const userMessage = error.error; // should give error body

      return throwError(userMessage);
    };
}
```

Sources :

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse

[Accessing HTTP Error Response Body from HttpInterceptor in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849689/accessing-http-error-response-body-from-httpinterceptor-in-angular)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the mistake. Many thanks for your help! I renamed the error type to `any` and with `error.json()` I can actually access the response body as normal. I do not know how I could overlook that ...

Thanks! It seems to work!