# Angular httpClient.post() cant fetch error object returned by API like Postman does

Tags: angular, api, httpresponse

## Edit [04.01.2020]

I figuered out, that the `string` that I am getting `"Bad Request"` is the message of my error object. (Message is not set). 
So when I am changing the API response so that the message contains my actual error object, it is fine.

```
let error = {error: {}, code: '', message: {error: {}, code: ''}};
if (err.code === 'DUPLICATE_ENTRY') {
  error.message.code = 'DUPLICATE_ENTRY';
  error.message.error = {
    columns: ["name"]
  };
}
```

So we could say, that this fixes my problem, but to be honest, thats not what im expecting. Am I missing something or is this the correct way, how this is supposed to work? Am I really supposed to put my actual error object into a pseudo message block?

---

## Technologies

I am using Angular 8 as Frontend and nest.js 6.12.9 with typeorm as API.

### Short description

The problem consists in being unable to parse the API response object within Angular. The error in Angular is just a string saying `Bad Request`

### Setup

API Controller

```
@Post()
async create(@Query() link: string, @Body() enrollment: Enrollment, @Res() res: Response) {
    this.enrollmentService.create(enrollment, link).then(tEntrollment => {
        delete tEntrollment.appointment;
        res.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).json(tEntrollment);
    }).catch((err) => {
        let id = this.makeid(10);
        console.log(`[${(new Date()).toDateString()} ${(new Date()).toTimeString()}] Code: ${id} - ${err}`);

        let error = {error: {}, code: ''};
        if (err.code === 'ER_DUP_ENTRY') {
            error.code = 'DUPLICATE_ENTRY';
            error.error = {
                columns: ["name"]
            };
        } else {
            error.error = {
                undefined: {
                    message: "Some error occurred. Please try again later or contact the support",
                    code: id
                }
            };
        }

        res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json(error);
    });
}
```

On posting an object like

```
{
  "additions": [],
  "driver": null,
  "passenger": { "requirement": 1 },
  "name": "Test",
  "comment": ""
}
```

the controller does, what it is supposed to do. In this case, the name `Test` is already in use, so the `.catch()` block handles the rest, and returns an error response with `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` and the object

```
{
    "error": {
        "columns": [
            "name"
        ]
    },
    "code": "DUPLICATE_ENTRY"
}
```

Note that this object is fetched by posting the call via Postman. So everything works fine here.

### Main Problem

Like mentioned, the problem is, that I am unable to get this response within my angular project.
The call is made by my `terminService` and looks as follows.

```
enroll(enrollment: IEnrollmentModel, appointment: IAppointmentModel): Observable<HttpEvent<IEnrollmentModel>> {
    const url = `${environment.api.url}enrollment?link=${appointment.link}`;
    // const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, {
    //   data: enrollment,
    //   observe: 'response',
    //   reportProgress: true,
    // });
    // return this.httpClient.request(req);
    return this.httpClient.post<IEnrollmentModel>(url, enrollment, {observe: 'response'});
  }
```

and the handling of this in my `ernollment.component.ts` looks like this

```
this.terminService.enroll(output, this.appointment).subscribe(result => {
        if (result.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          switch (result.status) {
            case HttpStatus.CREATED:
              this.router.navigate([`enroll`], {queryParams: {val: this.appointment.link}});
              break;
          }
        }
      }, error => {
        console.log(error)
        switch (error.status) {
          case HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST:
            if (error.code === 'DUPLICATE_ENTRY') {
              error.error.columns.forEach(fColumn => {
                  const uppercaseName = fColumn.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + fColumn.substring(1);
                  const fnName: string = 'get' + uppercaseName;
                  this[fnName]().setErrors({inUse: true});
              }
            });
            break;
        }
      }
    );
```

The posted object looks exactely like shown previously. Looking into the Chrome dev tools I can see, that the response from this API call is exactely like I expected it to be.
`{"error":{"columns":["name"]},"code":"DUPLICATE_ENTRY"}`. This is actually a good sign, but I am unable to get this response within Angular. When logging the error within `error => {}` I am just getting a string saying `Bad Request`. I also tried to log `error.status` `error.body` `error.error` and so on, but this just logs `undefined`, because error is no object. It is just a string.


What am i missing? How can I properly acces and parse the response, including object and HttpStatus returned by my API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular HttpClient error handling difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48311852/angular-httpclient-error-handling-difficult)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I tried `console.log(err.error)` and `console.log(err.error.message);`, but `err.error`is still undefined. I also speciefied `(err: HttpErrorResponse) => {}` instead of `err => {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So due to my discovery described in my edit, I was able to find my error.
The error, unfortunately, lies in no code piece I provided. It lies in a interceptor, checking for missing authentication.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
      if (err.status === 401) {
        // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
        this.authenticationService.logout();
        location.reload();
      }

      // const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;     <----- This Line
      // return throwError(err);

      return throwError(err);
    }));
  }
}
```

On recieving a `ErrorResponse`, the interceptor checks for the status `401` in order to redirect to the login page. Note the commented lines before the return statement. Right here, the error got parsed and shrinked, which is actually not what I want. Knowing that, I can pass the original error to the `throwError` function and I will get the expected result in my component.

Idea due to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19103#issuecomment-471973058) issue response.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular HttpClient seems to mangle the response a bit when trying to parse it as JSON. You can catch the original error on Observable level before the subscription:

```
yourObservable$.pipe(catchError((error) => console.log(error))).subscribe();
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. There is always `type 'void' is not assignable to type 'observableinput any '`. I then also can't call `result.type` within the subscription, because `property 'type' does not exist on type 'unknown'`.

Comment: Maybe this link here helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849689/accessing-http-error-response-body-from-httpinterceptor-in-angular

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am aware, that the error body should be available in the error property. But thath's not the case in my example. The error I am trying to access is no object, but a string. Even though the response of the API is accessible within the Chrome dev tools

Answer (score 0):

In your enroll method, replace the function return type i.e. replace "HttpEvent" with "HttpResponse". See sample below. Hopefully that fixes it.

```
enroll(enrollment: IEnrollmentModel, appointment: IAppointmentModel): Observable<HttpResponse<IEnrollmentModel>> {
    const url = `${environment.api.url}enrollment?link=${appointment.link}`;
    return this.httpClient.post<IEnrollmentModel>(url, enrollment, {observe: 'response'});
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. Still the same. But I figured something out, see my edit.